# Make sure sub directories don't listen to mod rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using some dynamic pages on every .html file in my root.

With the following line:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).html content.php?alias=$1 [L]
```

This works fine, but I also got some other websites on the same location, only a few folders down. I don't want them to listen to this line, everytime I create a .html file, I get redirect to content.php in my root.

Example:

Location of my content.php:

```
public_html/Website/content.php

public_html/Website/_intern/websites/index.html
```

The above file gets redirected to the content.php in my root.

How can I prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Tweak your regex. Instead of `.*` which matches anything you should use `[^/]+` to match anything but `/`. This ensures, you don't select anything in sub-directories:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.html$ content.php?alias=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: I think it does, but I got another mod rewrite which redirects urls with an _ to content.php The one I am testing has an underscore so how do I change the line to work with underscores? Like this? : `^([_^/]+)\.html$ content.php?alias=$1 [L,QSA,NC]`

Comment: If I got it correctly, your line shouldn't listen to any sub directories, but _intern is a subdirectory that still listens to: `RewriteRule    ^_(.*)/(.*).html /lp.php?alias=$2 [L]` even though it comes after your line.

Comment: Yo should first post your existing .htaccess in question so that I can advise you accordingly. Also do tell me what is full UR you're using to test this and what's not working?